# Replace items in a list without using .pop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**This is the question:**

A professor felt that scores on a test came out somewhat low. The professor decided to ***give 8% extra
credit to students whose score is less than 70, and 5% extra credit to students whose score is 70 or
more***. Write a Python program that:

- Stores the scores in a list, and print the initial scores, with a message:
- scores = [73.75, 39.45, 72.60, 45.50, 82.75, 97, 54.50, 48.00, 96.50 ]
- Using a loop, process each score to calculate the new score and **store it in the same list. You may
  not change the order of the list**, since the scores correspond to the class roster.
- Truncate each new score to be no more than 100 after adding the extra credit.
- Print the list of new scores, with a short message
- You may NOT use more than one list in your program.
- Your program must work on a list of any length. The list above is only for your program testing.

**My code:**

```
#this code shows old scores and prints the new scores of students 

position = 0 #initialize position for later 

scores = [73.75, 39.45, 72.60, 45.50, 82.75, 97, 54.50, 48.00, 96.50 ]
print ("\nThese are the old scores: ", scores)

for score in scores:
    if score < 70:
        score *= 1.08
    elif score >= 70:
        score *= 1.05
    scores.insert (position,float(format(score,".2f"))) #this adds the new score into position
    position += 1
    scores.pop (position) #this removes the old score which was pushed to +1 position

for position, score in enumerate(scores):
    if score > 100:
        scores[position] = 100

print ("These are the new scores:", scores)
```

He wants me to not use things like .pop, or enumerate and says there's a simpler way to do it but I just can't think of one. Please help!

Comment: why not _replacing_ the old value?

Comment: Just index the scores with position: `scores[position] = float(format(score, ".2f"))`

Comment: better: `scores[position] = score` you don't need format to convert back to float

Comment: `new_scores=[fix_score(old_score) for old_score in scores_list]`

Comment: "He wants me to not use things like .pop, or enumerate"

Comment: Look at your second loop: that's how you do it.  Just directly replace the old value with the new one.

Comment: but it's using `enumerate`. That's ridiculous now :) can the teacher post the answer ?

Comment: People who got 70% or 71% are not going to be happy with this.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds: the text says not to create a new list: `scores[:] = (min(100, (1.08 if score < 70 else 1.05) * score) for score in scores)`

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds: At least where I'm from, "8% extra credit" would always mean "+ 0.08", not "* 1.08".

Comment: Jeez I am so bad at reading requirements. @user2357112 good catch, I was just assuming what the OP wrote was correct.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds: Oh hey, you're right, the code in the question does the same thing. It should probably be doing `score += 8` or `score += 5` instead of multiplying.

Comment: @user2357112 are confirming then this is an additonal 5% of 100 towards your grade, not 5% extra of your current grade?

Comment: @user2357112 in terms of relevance for breaking 100 it wont change effect those, but the kid with 75 could jump to a B!

Comment: Can we all agree this is a terrible assignment? Generally forces you to use non-Pythonic constructs, storing data which belongs to a key (a student) not in a dictionary (nor keeping them contained together in any other structure), ambiguity on what the percentage applies to, and the overall scheme actually unfairly gives advantages to students with 67, 68, 69 points. Who writes this stuff?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I suspect whoever wrote this was one of those students with 67, 68, 69 points :), looking out for his own

Comment: my teacher is strict and weird :( can't argue with him, he's been teaching the course for years and wouldn't listen to feedback anyways. Anyways, thanks @everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `range(len)` in place of enumerate

```
scores = [73.75, 39.45, 72.60, 45.50, 82.75, 97, 54.50, 48.00, 96.50 ]
print(scores)

for i in range(len(scores)):
    if scores[i] < 70:
        scores[i] = round(scores[i]*1.08, 2)
        if scores[i] > 100:
            scores[i] = 100
    elif scores[i] > 70:
        scores[i] = round(scores[i]*1.05, 2)
        if scores[i] > 100:
            scores[i] = 100

print(scores)
# [77.44, 42.61, 76.23, 49.14, 86.89, 100, 58.86, 51.84, 100]
```

Comment: @roganjosh he's not allowed to use enumerate

Comment: I suspect this is "cheating" but fair enough :)

Comment: @roganjosh I wonder how many times SO ruined the actual in class curve ;)

Answer (score 0):

Look at your second loop: that's how you do it. Just directly replace the old value with the new one.

```
for i in range(len(scores)):
    if scores[i] < 70:
        scores[i] *= 1.08
    elif scores[i] >= 70:
        scores[i] *= 1.05
```

No more `insert` and `pop`.

Comment: See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52748765/replace-items-in-a-list-without-using-pop#comment92422150_52748765)

Comment: (except with 8 and 5 instead of 0.08 and 0.05, because that comment was written for percentages scaled to 0-1 instead of 0-100)

Comment: `Truncate each new score to be no more than 100 after adding the extra credit.` we are getting graded on this assignment

Comment: Yes, there are other problems.  I'm holding my answer to the question asked: how to replace items without `pop`.  OP can make the other adaptations, or ask a separate question if stuck.  The comments should suffice.